# vuejs remove item from array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form value which gets id's each time i save data, but if i delete any of those data the id of it won't be deleted from form value.

```
data() {
  return {
    savedVariations: [],
    form: {
      variations: [],
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  addVariants(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('/api/admin/variations/store', {
      childs: this.variationChilds,
      parent: this.variationParents,
    })
    .then(res => {
      this.form.variations.push(res.data.data.id); // send id to form.variations
    })
  },
  removeSavedParent(id, index){
    axios.delete('/api/admin/variations/destroy/'+id).then((res) => {
      this.form.variations.splice(id); // delete the id from form.variations (not working)
      this.savedVariations.splice(index, 1);
    })
  },
}
```

> When i save new item my `form.variations` becomes
>   `variations["1","50", "30"]` but when i delete any of those items the
>   id won't be removed from `form.variations`

**Any idea how to remove id from form variable when i delete the data?**

Comment: `Array.prototype.splice` needs to know how many elements to delete. "`this.form.variations.splice(id, 1)`" might work. (See 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice').

Comment: @Cat that didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find the index of id in your array and remove it, see code below

```
this.form.variations.splice(this.form.variations.indexOf(id), 1);
```